# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I try to run

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

but got the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-46a8a2031c9c> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets'
```

I have the tensorflow_datasets results, below is a snippets of `pip list`

```
tensorboard                        2.1.1              
tensorflow                         2.1.0              
tensorflow-datasets                2.1.0              
tensorflow-estimator               2.1.0              
tensorflow-hub                     0.7.0              
tensorflow-metadata                0.21.1
```

I am running using Ubuntu 16.04 with Anaconda virtual environment. How should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue as jupyterlab does not pickup the virtual environment. We need to set according to the following: https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/